# Crash happened when switch Cobalt js engine to V8

Tags: v8, cobalt

To preview on Cobalt master(16.154703), everything works well with mosjs-45.
But when we switch engine to V8, a crash occurred

```
v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray() [0x8693f0]
v8::internal::TemplateList::New() [0x93bcec]
v8::internal::Heap::CreateApiObjects() [0xd6ad40]
v8::internal::Heap::CreateHeapObjects() [0xd6cc7c]
v8::internal::Isolate::Init() [0x909164]
v8::SnapshotCreator::SnapshotCreator() [0x70dbac]
v8::V8::CreateSnapshotDataBlob() [0x73c8b8]
cobalt::script::v8c::IsolateFellowship::InitializeStartupData() [0x70a58c]
cobalt::script::v8c::IsolateFellowship::IsolateFellowship() [0x70ad1c
cobalt::script::v8c::V8cEngine::V8cEngine() [0x6fa494]
cobalt::script::JavaScriptEngine::CreateEngine() [0x6fa63c]
cobalt::browser::WebModule::Impl::Impl() [0xbd4bc]
cobalt::browser::WebModule::Initialize() [0xbef4c]
(anonymous namespace)::RunAndSignal() [0xe4914]
MessageLoop::RunTask() [0xe50bc]
MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask() [0xe5b5c]
MessageLoop::DoWork() [0xe7b54]
base::MessagePumpDefault::Run() [0xe9428]
base::RunLoop::Run() [0xf2d10]
MessageLoop::Run() [0xe4a00]
```

It seems HandleScope has not been created, and the address 0x1 of 
'isolate->handle_scope_data()->next' leads to this crash. I am not sure whether this issue is specific, please help us on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please test against the latest Cobalt 16.162639 and report the issue to the Issue Tracker?

https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/b626c97d51f3afb82cce662b06c25b10a7d897d5
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:181120

Comment: I confirm this issue also exists on Cobalt 16.162639,and report this to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79159114

Comment: Please follow up from that issue tracker.